# PHP result of combined string

Tags: php, string, variables

Can anyone tell me why the result of the following expression:

```
$temp=3+"60%"+"$20"
```

**is 63**

What signs "$" and "%" mean in PHP programming language?

Comment: They're simply string characters, with no special meaning.... your math is trying to imbue them with some special meaning

Comment: Loose typing means PHP will try to convert your strings to numbers to use in arithmetic (your `+`), working from left to right until it encounters  non-numeric character; so it can convert `"60%"` to `60`, but can't convert `"$20"` to anything, so it treats it as 0; so 3+60+0 = 63

Comment: It makes sense. Could you post your comment as a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note you're performing addition of numbers (not string concatenation).

For this reason the interpreter attempts to convert strings to numbers before performing sums.

Parsing a string, as digits are encountered the resulting number is built up. As a non-digit is encountered the conversion ends**.

`"60%"` is converted to `60`. The `%` has no meaning, is simply discarded.

`"$20"` is converted to `0` because as the `$` sign is encountered string to int conversion is aborted.

So you have `60+3`

The dollar sign inside a double quote string actually have a special meaning if followed by the name of a variable: the content of the variable is placed into the string so:

```
$a = "20";
$b = "10" + "$a"; // --> 30
```

---

(**) There are some exceptions: `"10E3"` is converted as `10E3` = `1000`;

`"10.2"` in converted to `10.2`. The whole operation turn into a sum of floating point numbers.